Could a husband force a paternity test and divorce in 1940s New York?
My question is inspired by the Hitchcock film Strangers on a Train.
Our hero, Guy, is married to a woman who has been cheating on him, hounding him for a divorce for a year, and who is now pregnant with a lover's child. Guy is looking forward to the divorce because he's in love with another woman, and wants to be free to marry her. But when he returns home to meet his wife and divorce lawyer, she reveals she has changed her mind about the divorce, intends to force him to stay in the marriage, and also to carry the child. He asks, "Why me? It's not my baby." She replies, "Yes, but people don't know that, Guy."
This is the predicament the movie sets to give the hero a plausible motive for murder. I'm curious how airtight it is.
My question: if Guy could prove his wife had been unfaithful, and that the child was not his, could he obtain a divorce over her objection?
Proof
I assume a paternity test could settle the matter, but they are a relatively recent invention, and for most of the 20th century, tests could only disqualify a significant fraction of the population (Wikipedia: 1920s: 30%; 1930s: 40%; 1960s: 80%). So, the date matters.
The setting's year is ambiguous, there being no title card or other explicit mention of a date. The story was written in 1950 and filmed in '51, but that doesn't mean the movie is set in 1951. In an early scene, the villain tells Guy that he has flown on a "jet plane" -- this may be a fabrication, but Guy understands the phrase, and jets were invented in ~1939, so we can be certain that tests based on serological testing (40% exclusion rate) existed. Guy is a newly-rich tennis star with a Senator as a wannabe father-in-law, so I think we can assume he'd have access to a test -- if the law cared, and if the law would have allowed him to obtain one over his wife's objections.
Jurisdiction
This is also ambiguous and difficult to pin down. Guy and Miriam live in "Metcalf" (and presumably were married there), which it turns out is fictional; those parts of the film were shot in Danbury, Connecticut. (There are real Metcalfs in Georgia and Massachusetts, but those locations are disqualified by other story facts.) The dialogue suggests that Guy's Metcalf is in or near New York. At the time of the murder, he's on a train from New York to Washington. So: New York state.

Would a man of some means, living and married in New York State in the 1940s, have been legally able to obtain a paternity test over his wife's objections, and subsequently divorce her if the test happened to conclusively prove that the child was someone else's?

Reg. Time: The first jet planes flew 1944 (Me262) and the first not military ones (de Havilland DH.106 Comet) only came 1949, but only flew commercially 1952.

Are we assuming that the only possible way to prove adultery is to prove that the child was not Guy's?  Before the no-fault divorce changes, you could certainly get a divorce in New York by proving adultery.  It seems unlikely that a 1950's serological test would be the best evidence of adultery one could introduce unless the wife had been very, very discreet over the course of the year.

@Trish according to Wikipedia, the development of the Me 262 began in 1939, with test flights beginning on 1941 and the first under jet power in 1942.  1944 is the year it first saw operational use.  It's certainly conceivable that jet airplanes could have been mentioned in fiction as early as the 1920s, as engineers had by then already recognized the limitations of piston aircraft and begun working on designs for jet engines, even if none were built before the following decade.  And the He 178 did indeed fly in 1939.

@phoog it's much more likely he flew a production machine than a test machine because I know of only ~6 test pilots that survived the war and piloted test machines: There was only a single documented pilot of any He 178 (Erich Warsitz), the He 280 had only 9 built, all prototypes that saw flight were piloted by Fritz Schäfer (though he survived the loss of one airframe) before the project was canned. Me 262 had, as far as I know, at best 2-3 test pilots (Fey, who defected, and Wendel, who did the first flight), the Ar 234 killed its first test pilots in flight 2 and Erich Sommer replaced him.

So while possible that "the villain" is one of these pilots, it's very much more likely the film is set after November 1945, assuming Guy is a released german ex-Luftwaffe pilot who flew a production jet, though it is much more likely that the film is set in 1950 to 1952 (anticipating the coming commercial jet plane flights), as the film at other times references the war as having passed. My main point of contentionis, that we need to date the film as 1950+, not 1940+

If the husband was gone on a long trip (several months) when the baby was conceived, that would be enough to prove he could not be the father.

@Trish there was no production He 178; it was a test model.  So the probability that this flight of the He 178 was zero.  If "he" in your sentence is the fictional character, then it really does not matter whether it was a production or test machine.  The story doesn't mention its setting, so absent any anachronism, we can assume it's "present day," so 1950/51.  In any event, the point of my comment was to point out that the assessment that having "flown on a jet plane" implies the setting to be after 1939 is more or less accurate, contrary to your first comment.

@Trish while it's more likely that the time is 1950 or later, the jet plane comment by itself does not exclude a setting in the 1940s.  It's impossible for the flight in question to have been on a commercial airliner unless the setting is in the future, because they were not in service when the script was written nor when the film was produced.  (Furthermore, the character is unlikely to be a pilot; flying "on" a plane means "as a passenger"; if he had been the pilot of a jet plane he would have said "flown a jet plane" without a preposition.)

@phoog if we exclude all military fighter planes, and also exclude the film being set any time after the publication, that leaves a very narrow gap of 49/50 where a few demonstration flights by the de Havilland DH.106 Comet did transport a few officers of airlines. There were about 500 hours of test and demonstration flights by the 2nd prototype of the DH-106 carrying airline observers,, which could be considered one of the few possibilities to be on a jet plane before 1951/52.

Another option could have been that for some reason he was transported by a  Stratofreighter, which would put the setting to about 47-50. In either way, we are no earlier than about 47.

Accurate paternity tests came long after 1940s as the OP notes. At most, they could determine if the blood types were possible.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not primarily about law. It is primary about dating a historically rooted story and the technology of paternity tests.

@ohwilleke: The comments are primarily about dating the story and establishing the level of available technology at the time, but they seem like a mere tangent to me. The question itself, as I read it, is primarily about New York State divorce law c. 1950 (± 10 years or so). I think we can take it as a given that a paternity test would be (technically) an option, but subject (and presumably known to be subject) to a fairly high false positive rate.

There were no legally accepted paternity tests in the 1940's. This is not a question about the law. I am a staunch oppositor of question migrations but this one belongs on Worldbuilding, not Law.

@ohwilleke I'm sorry if my recital of some of the facts seems like an off-topic digression, but as I noted, the film is notably ambiguous about both date and location, so I wanted to nail those areas down as tightly as possible. My core question really is just about the legal options available to a man caught in the predicament arranged by the film.

@JustinCave I don't want to focus exclusively on paternity testing as an recourse, but to a layperson like myself it seems like the elephant in the room, so that's what I focused my own research on, and I shared the results since SE generally asks folks to do that. I am certainly interested in any other options that would have been available to Guy. Having never been married, divorced, or a father, all this territory is alien to me.

@ohwilleke the comments about dating are just trying to figure out the applicable legal basis of which law would be in effect.

FWIW: At least in the novel that Hitchcock adapted, Guy lives in New York but Metcalf is in Texas. The divorce would therefore likely proceed under Texas law.


Would a man of some means, living and married in New York State in the
1940s, have been legally able to obtain a paternity test over his
wife's objections, and subsequently divorce her if the test happened
to conclusively prove that the child was someone else's?

The scenario proposed, of a demand for a paternity test in connection with a fault based divorce case, would have been rare and risky.
New York State had fault based divorce in the 1940s as did all other U.S. states at the time. Adultery was a ground for divorce in every U.S. state at the time. New York State was the last U.S. state to adopt no fault divorce, and it did so in the year 2010. (Judicial fault based divorce was available in every U.S. state by sometime in the early to mid-1800s. Before that, state legislatures granted divorces in their sole and absolute discretion.)
Paternity testing was in its infancy at that time, and was only conclusive in the minority of cases where the child's blood type was inconsistent with the blood types that the husband and wife could together produce (typically excluding 30%-40% of possible fathers). True paternity tests didn't exist. The risk of a blood type comparison that doesn't rule out a father's paternity seeming to support an adulterous spouse's defense also discouraged their use. Often, it was impossible to determine paternity at the time. Highly accurate paternity testing is a much more modern phenomena, and it was prohibitively expensive for most domestic relations litigants until long after it was possible.
Usually, someone could obtain a spouse's blood type from other sources than a litigation related test, such as from hospital or medical records. (Privacy from a spouse for medical records would have been the exception and not the rule. This long predated federal and state medical privacy laws.)
"Scientific"  proof of non-paternity usually involved either (1) the absence of the husband at war or at sea or in prison or otherwise absent at the time that the pregnancy had to have started, or (2) based upon the child being racially completely different from the child that the husband and wife would have produced (although is now famously known to be not 100% accurate as a child with a different racial phenotype is possible if both husband and wife have cryptic ancestry from another race that the one that they phenotypically appear to be a part of, something not widely known at that time).
Pre-trial discovery in domestic relations cases in that era was rare, and expert witnesses were rare and expensive and viewed with some skepticism in divorce cases in that era. Most adultery cases were established either by a confession of a party, or by the work of a private investigator (a bread and butter source of demand for members of that profession from at least the 1920s or 1930s until no fault divorce was adopted).
Also, it is worth recalling that in fault based divorce, it was not enough to show that the other spouse committed one of the grounds for a fault based divorce. It also had to be based on a relatively recent incident (not an issue in this case) or the defense of condonation would apply, and you had to show that the spouse seeking the divorce was not guilty of any of the grounds for a fault based divorce. If both spouses were at fault, a divorce was not an option. So, if the spouse lying about her own affair also lied about her husband having an affair and the judge believed her, there would be either a divorce with him at fault, or no divorce if the judge believed that both of them were at fault.

The first general divorce law in the State of New York was enacted in
1787, providing for judicial divorce on the grounds of adultery.' For
nearly two centuries, adultery remained the sole ground for divorce in
New York. Under new section 170 of the Domestic Relations Law, which
took effect on September 1, 1967, New York has five grounds for
divorce in addition to adultery: 2 cruelty; abandonment; imprisonment;
judicial separation for two years; and separation pursuant to a
written agreement for two years.

From a law review article from 1968. Neighboring states (and distant states like Nevada) adopted addition grounds for divorce sooner than New York State did.
